# Get result of array after it got modified in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, callback

Using Javascript
Get result of array after it got modified in a for loop || .forEach || for-in?

The problem is that javascript runs everything asynchronously, whereby I can't find a solution to this seemingly simple problem.

Example:

```
action: function () {
    modelsResult = [];

    Model.forEach(function (model) {
        doSomething(model, function (newModel) {
        modelsResult.push(newModel);
    });

    response.send({
        models: modelsResult
    });
}

var doSomething = function (model, callback) {
    model.id = model.id++;

    callback(model);
}
```

`response.send` will be executed before modelsResult has all the models that the forEach provides. If I however put the `response.send` within the forEach, then same will happen.

Comment: Are any of these operations asynchronous?  If so, please tell us which ones because that changes the flow of code entirely.

Comment: Also, you appear to be missing so close braces so it is not clear how the execution flows.  Please correct the missing braces and fix the indentation so we can follow the flow of the code.

Comment: doSomething is asynchronous. Tryed to clearify the exe flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If doSomething is asynchronous, then you will have to significantly restructure your code.  You cannot write sequential code with asynchronous operations and expect things to follow the sequential path.  They simply do not.

Instead, you will have to structure your code so that you know when the last asynchronous `doSomething()` operation has completed and then, and only then, can you do your `response.send()` with the results of all the asynchronous operations.

I don't know what exactly a `Model` is in your code, but if we can know ahead of time how many iterations there will be with `.forEach()` call on it, then your code could be implemented like this:

```
action: function () {
    modelsResult = [];

    // create a count of remaining iterations       
    var cntRemaining = Model.length;

    Model.forEach(function (model) {
        doSomething(model, function (newModel) {

            // save results of this async operation
            modelsResult.push(newModel);

            // one more async operation has completed
            --cntRemaining;

            // if all async calls are done, then process the final result
            if (cntRemaining === 0) {
                response.send({models: modelsResult});
            }
        });
    });

}

var doSomething = function (model, callback) {
    ++model.id;

    callback(model);
}
```

Comment: I simply can't a restructure code in a way that can solve my problem. Guess there doesn't exist one. Wanted to ask on the forum first though, always possible I'm missing something simple :/

Comment: @user1933169 - I've added an example of how your code could be restructured to account for the asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of libs can help you with this. Or you can write your own little boolean in the function that only gets set when the index is same as the length, thus kicking off your final callback... Save the work though for something intersting; I suggest having a look at Q or underscore, lots of different ways to achieve this.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q
http://underscorejs.org/#after